# Joomla Access Level not working as Expected

Tags: joomla

I have two users.
user1 - pkj@abc.com - user group and access level - `Business Owner`
`Business Owners` access level is only `Business Owners`

user2 - pkj@xyz.com - user group and access level - `Registered`
access level is `registered, manager,super users`

Now user1 can access the contents of both `registered` and `business owner`
and user2 can access the contents of only `registered` and not `business owner`(which is correct as expected)

What I expect is that since `business owner`(user1) has not been given access for registered, he should not be able to access the contents of `Registered`

Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it happens because Business owners group is a sublevel of Registered, you put Registered as its father group , so this group inherit alll the privileges from Registed, try putting as father group **Public** from Business owners

Comment: That doesn't work. If you make business group member of public, Joomla doesn't allow you to login.

Comment: maybe you can create another access level and group that have access to content for user 2 and assign it to user 2, 
I can not think of another option, hope help